# Write to S3 bucket using Async/Await in AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, async-await, aws-lambda

I have been using the code below (which I have now added await to) to send files to S3. It has worked fine with my lambda code but as I move to transfer larger files like MP4 I feel I need async/await.

How can I fully convert this to async/await?

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
...
// Copy data to a variable to enable write to S3 Bucket
var result = response.audioContent;
console.log('Result contents ', result);

// Set S3 bucket details and put MP3 file into S3 bucket from tmp
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
await var params = {
Bucket: 'bucketname',
Key: filename + ".txt",
ACL: 'public-read',
Body: result
};

await s3.putObject(params, function (err, result) {
if (err) console.log('TXT file not sent to S3 - FAILED'); // an error occurred
else console.log('TXT file sent to S3 - SUCCESS');    // successful response
context.succeed('TXT file has been sent to S3');
});
```

Comment: You don't need to use `await var params = ...` `await` is only useful for promises

Answer (score 36):

You only `await` functions that return a promise. `s3.putObject` does not return a promise (similar to most functions that take a callback). It returns a `Request` object. If you want to use async/await, you need to chain the `.promise()` method onto the end of your `s3.putObject` call and remove the callback (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html#promise-property)

```
try { // You should always catch your errors when using async/await
  const s3Response = await s3.putObject(params).promise();
  callback(null, s3Response);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
  callback(e);
}
```

Comment: I think this is right on track, except you probably also don't want to use the deprecated `context.succeed()` here, since that's mixing async/await and callbacks.  Return a response or a promise, since you're inside an async function (the handler), yes?

Comment: What should ```context.succeed(s3Response);``` be replaced with in an async/await situation?

Comment: Perhaps ```callback(null, s3Response);```?

Comment: Yes, I wasn't sure about the `context.succeed`. I did a little research, and the context object is really just to provide additional information about the lambda request (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html).

Instead of `context.succeed` you want to call `callback(null, s3Response)`. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 9):

As @djheru said, Async/Await only works with functions that return promises.
I would recommend creating a simple wrapper function to assist with this problem.

```js
const putObjectWrapper = (params) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    s3.putObject(params, function (err, result) {
      if(err) reject(err);
      if(result) resolve(result);
    });
  })
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
const result = await putObjectWrapper(params);
```

Here is a really great resource on Promises and Async/Await:

https://javascript.info/async

Comment: i guess small change needed if(err) resolve(err); should be replaced by if(err) reject(err);