# how to asynchronous upload files to AWS S3 in express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

I want to store several images to S3, then store the returned `imageUrls in MongoDB in express JS fn.

What I did to achieve this was that.

```js
module.exports.postController = async (req, res) => {

  const files = req.files;

  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const imageArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var params = {
        Bucket: "apple-fiona",
        Key: "items" + "/" + Date.now() + "_" + files[i].originalname,
        Body: files[i].buffer,
        ContentType: files[i].mimetype,
        ACL: "public-read",
      };
      s3bucket.upload(params, async (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500).json({ errors: [{ message: "Server error" }] });
        } else {
          imageArr.push(data.Location);
        }
      });
    }
    resolve(imageArr);
  })
    .then((imageArr) => {
      console.log(imageArr, "sueecess")
      // i want to stroe imageArr to mongodb here... 
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err, "er"));
};
```

I thought the result of console.log would be definitely array with imageUrls which comes from `data.Location`, but I got empty array in the console like this `[]`.
doesn't `resolve()` in promise wait until everything is finished before going to then?

promise sometimes very tricky
I also used `await` like this

```js
const imageArr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  console.log("files i");
  console.log(files[i]);
  var params = {
    Bucket: "apple-fiona",
    Key: "items" + "/" + Date.now() + "_" + files[i].originalname,
    Body: files[i].buffer,
    ContentType: files[i].mimetype,
    ACL: "public-read",
  };
  await s3bucket.upload(params, async (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).json({ errors: [{ message: "Server error" }] });
    } else {
      console.log("run", data.Location);
      imageArr.push(data.Location);
    };
  })
}

console.log(imageArr)
```

but gave me the same result.
how could I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to synchronously upload files to S3 using aws-sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57420576/how-to-synchronously-upload-files-to-s3-using-aws-sdk)

Comment: I am afraid that no.... because  all files uploading in for loop has to complete before going to then( ) .

Comment: This answer shows how to use async/await in the same context

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55012698/747834

Answer (score 0):

After doing some search on StackOverflow, I have managed to figure out what to do to accomplish this on my own.
this is the answer.

```
const files = req.files;

  const imageArr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

    var params = {
      Bucket: "apple-fiona",
      Key: "items" + "/" + Date.now() + "_" + files[i].originalname,
      Body: files[i].buffer,
      ContentType: files[i].mimetype,
      ACL: "public-read",
    };
    s3bucket.upload(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ errors: [{ message: "Server error" }] });
      } else {
        imageArr.push(data.Location);

        if (i + 1 === files.length) {

          fn(imageArr);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  const fn = (imageArr) => {
    console.log("--imageArr new-------");
    console.log(imageArr);
  };
```

as above, I called a function only the last time the for loop runs in s3 callback. that made sure to put all imageUrl to imageArr when the fn is called. 
this might not be the best solution but for me, it's pretty much perfect !!

Comment: This answer shows how to use async/await https://stackoverflow.com/a/55012698/747834